# Pytest: got an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, fastapi

I have a class whose **init** takes some named arguments like this

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, api_key, debug=False, root_url="https://app.apitoolkit.io",
                 headers=['authorization', 'cookie'],
                 fields_one=[], fields_two=[]):
        print(api_key,debug, root_url, headers, fields_one, fields_two)
```

I use the class like this

```py
client = MyClass(
    api_key="myapikey",
    root_url="http://example.com",
    headers=["one", "two"],
    fields_one=["field1", "fields2"],
    fields_two=["field_three", "fields4"],
    debug=True
)
```

And this works normally when run (using it with fastapi) the server runs normally.
but I get this error when I test it using pytest
`TypeError: MyClass.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'api_key'`
and when I make root_url (or any other argument) the first I get
`TypeError: MyClass.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'root_url'`

I deleted pytest cache and all other pycaches but the error persists

pytest code

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from myclass import MyClass

app = FastAPI()

client = MyClass(
    api_key="<API_KEY>",
    root_url="http://localhost:8080",
    headers=["authorization", "content-type", "connection"],
    fields_one=["name", "email"],
    fields_two=["password", "phone"],
    debug=True
)

app.middleware('http')(client.middleware)

@app.post("/hello")
async def read_main():
    return {"Hello": "World"}

client = TestClient(app)

def test_read_main():
    response = client.post("/hello", json={"name": "john"})
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == {"Hello": "World"}
```

Comment: Could you also share your pytest code?

Comment: @taxevader I updated the question with the pytest code

Comment: @Guy I have only one  MyClass imported in the test file

Comment: Your pytest code doesn't seem to import `pytest` library so I can't run the code with `pytest` command. Did you test it by running `python <test file>`  instead? Also your `MyClass`  object (`client`) doesn't have `middleware` property that is used at `app.middleware('http')(client.middleware)`. Is it initialized somewhere

Comment: @taxevader You don't need to import pytest to run the code with pytest

Comment: I think it was importing a different version of MyClass (cached?), I moved the test file under myclass module (folder) and imported MyClass using `from . import MyClass` and it worked.